# Dynamic TextBoxes not changing value ASP.Net and C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic, onclick

I'm currently filling text boxes dynamically on page load. Then I'm using an OnClick command to pull the info from said text boxes

My ASPX Table

```
<div class="mi_Container" id="Edit">
<div class="mi_Title">
    <asp:Label ID="App_Name_E" runat="server" />
</div>
<hr />
<table class="mi_Inner_Container">
    <tr>
        <td class="mi_Desc">
            Description: <br />
            <asp:TextBox ID="Description_E"  Rows="6" CssClass="mi_Textarea" TextMode="MultiLine" runat="server" />
        </td>
        <td class="mi_Center">
            Upload Test Script:<br />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="mi_Rows">
            Application Owner: <br />
            <asp:TextBox ID="App_Owner_E" runat="server" />
        </td>
        <td class="mi_Center">
            <div class="mi_Img_Icons">
                Migration Status:<br />
                <asp:DropDownList ID="CS_E" runat="server" DataSourceID="Migration_Status_Source" DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="ID"></asp:DropDownList>
            </div>
            <div class="mi_Img_Icons">
                Migration Progress:<br />
                <asp:DropDownList ID="CP_E" runat="server" DataSourceID="Migration_Progress_Source" DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="ID"></asp:DropDownList>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="mi_Rows">
            Technical Service Owner: <br />
            <asp:TextBox ID="TSO_E" runat="server" />
        </td>
        <td class="mi_Center">   
            Migration Phase: <br />
            <asp:DropDownList ID="Migration_Phase_E" runat="server" DataSourceID="Migration_Phase_Source" DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="ID"></asp:DropDownList>
        </td>
    </tr>
            <tr class="mi_Rows">
        <td>
            Responsible Manager: <br />
            <asp:TextBox ID="Responsible_Manager_E" runat="server" />
        </td>
        <td class="mi_Center">
            Next Steps: <br />
            <asp:TextBox ID="Next_Steps_E" runat="server" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="mi_Rows">
        <td>
            Signed Off by: <br />
            <asp:TextBox ID="Sign_Off_E" runat="server" />
        </td>
        <td class="mi_Center">
            <asp:Button ID="Update" runat="server" Text="Update Application" onclick="Update_Click" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

My C# Code Behind (Relevant)

```
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ((Label)Master.FindControl("titleBar")).Text = "More Information";

        float ID = float.Parse(Request.QueryString["ID"]);
        DataTable tbl = appsql.appSpecific(ID);

        App_Name_E.Text = tbl.Rows[0]["App_Name"].ToString();
        Description_E.Text = tbl.Rows[0]["Description"].ToString();
        App_Owner_E.Text = tbl.Rows[0]["App_Owner"].ToString();
        CS_E.SelectedIndex = (Convert.ToInt16(tbl.Rows[0]["Coexistence_Status"].ToString()));
        CP_E.SelectedIndex = (Convert.ToInt16(tbl.Rows[0]["Coexistence_Progress"].ToString()));
        TSO_E.Text = tbl.Rows[0]["TSO"].ToString();
        Migration_Phase_E.SelectedIndex = (Convert.ToInt16(tbl.Rows[0]["Migration_Phase"].ToString())) + 1;
        Responsible_Manager_E.Text = tbl.Rows[0]["Responsible_Manager"].ToString();
        Next_Steps_E.Text = tbl.Rows[0]["Next_steps"].ToString();
        Sign_Off_E.Text = tbl.Rows[0]["Sign_Off"].ToString();
    }

    protected void Update_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string DESC = Description_E.Text;
        string AO = App_Owner_E.Text;
        float CS = float.Parse(CS_E.SelectedValue);
        float CP = float.Parse(CP_E.SelectedValue);
        string TSO = TSO_E.Text;
        float MP = float.Parse(Migration_Phase_E.SelectedValue);
        string RM = Responsible_Manager_E.Text;
        string NS = Next_Steps_E.Text;
        string SO = Sign_Off_E.Text;


        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["app_migrationConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
        {

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Apps SET Description = @DESC, App_Owner = @AO, Coexistence_Progress = @CP, Coexistence_Status = @CS, TSO = @TSO, Migration_Phase = @MP, Responsible_Manager = @RM, Next_Steps = @NS, Sign_Off = @SO, Last_Update = @LU Where ID = @ID", connection);

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Float);
            cmd.Parameters["@ID"].Value = float.Parse(Request.QueryString["ID"]);

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@DESC", SqlDbType.VarChar, -1);
            cmd.Parameters["@DESC"].Value = DESC;

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@AO", SqlDbType.VarChar, -1);
            cmd.Parameters["@AO"].Value = AO;

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@CS", SqlDbType.Float);
            cmd.Parameters["@CS"].Value = CS;

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@CP", SqlDbType.Float);
            cmd.Parameters["@CP"].Value = CP;

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@TSO", SqlDbType.VarChar, -1);
            cmd.Parameters["TSO"].Value = TSO;

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@MP", SqlDbType.VarChar, -1);
            cmd.Parameters["@MP"].Value = MP;

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@RM", SqlDbType.VarChar, -1);
            cmd.Parameters["@RM"].Value = RM;

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@NS", SqlDbType.VarChar, -1);
            cmd.Parameters["@NS"].Value = NS;

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@SO", SqlDbType.VarChar, -1);
            cmd.Parameters["@SO"].Value = SO;

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@LU", SqlDbType.DateTime);
            cmd.Parameters["@LU"].Value = DateTime.Now;
            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                connection.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
    }
```

So, when I run the OnClick it does run the SQL Command correctly because the last update field copies correctly and updates the SQL Row. My problem is that all of the other variables are not set to the new value.

I've been posting questions lately all for this one project, which happens to be the first time I've worked with ASP

I'm assuming it has something to do with how the page is handling the variables. Me just changing the values isn't setting them again.

Any and all help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My problem is that all of the other variables are not set to the new value.

I assume that the values don't change in database since you're always loading them in `Page_Load` before they get updated in the event-handler.

You just have to wrap it in a `!PostBack`-check:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
        ((Label)Master.FindControl("titleBar")).Text = "More Information";

        float ID = float.Parse(Request.QueryString["ID"]);
        DataTable tbl = appsql.appSpecific(ID);

        App_Name_E.Text = tbl.Rows[0]["App_Name"].ToString();
        Description_E.Text = tbl.Rows[0]["Description"].ToString();
        App_Owner_E.Text = tbl.Rows[0]["App_Owner"].ToString();
        CS_E.SelectedIndex = (Convert.ToInt16(tbl.Rows[0]["Coexistence_Status"].ToString()));
        CP_E.SelectedIndex = (Convert.ToInt16(tbl.Rows[0]["Coexistence_Progress"].ToString()));
        TSO_E.Text = tbl.Rows[0]["TSO"].ToString();
        Migration_Phase_E.SelectedIndex = (Convert.ToInt16(tbl.Rows[0]["Migration_Phase"].ToString())) + 1;
        Responsible_Manager_E.Text = tbl.Rows[0]["Responsible_Manager"].ToString();
        Next_Steps_E.Text = tbl.Rows[0]["Next_steps"].ToString();
        Sign_Off_E.Text = tbl.Rows[0]["Sign_Off"].ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 Also, if the textboxes have already been filled (The user has already clicked the button), you may need to clear the values on each button click.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your controls may be resetting to the old values in the Page_Load event.  Typically, the block of populating the controls is wrapped in `if (!IsPostback) { ... }` so that they are only populated when the page loads the first time (ie. is not a postback).

So, in your case, you would have the following:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ((Label)Master.FindControl("titleBar")).Text = "More Information";

    if (!IsPostback)
    {
        float ID = float.Parse(Request.QueryString["ID"]);
        DataTable tbl = appsql.appSpecific(ID);
        App_Name_E.Text = tbl.Rows[0]["App_Name"].ToString();
        Description_E.Text = tbl.Rows[0]["Description"].ToString();
        App_Owner_E.Text = tbl.Rows[0]["App_Owner"].ToString();
        CS_E.SelectedIndex = (Convert.ToInt16(tbl.Rows[0]["Coexistence_Status"].ToString()));
        CP_E.SelectedIndex = (Convert.ToInt16(tbl.Rows[0]["Coexistence_Progress"].ToString()));
        TSO_E.Text = tbl.Rows[0]["TSO"].ToString();
        Migration_Phase_E.SelectedIndex = (Convert.ToInt16(tbl.Rows[0]["Migration_Phase"].ToString())) + 1;
        Responsible_Manager_E.Text = tbl.Rows[0]["Responsible_Manager"].ToString();
        Next_Steps_E.Text = tbl.Rows[0]["Next_steps"].ToString();
        Sign_Off_E.Text = tbl.Rows[0]["Sign_Off"].ToString();
    }
}
```

This will stop your controls from being reinitialized each time on Page_Load, which will allow your `Update_Click` method to pick up the new values and update the database correctly.